# Laravel 5.4 multiple (dynamic) form & square brackets

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, laravel-5.4, square-bracket

I use Laravel 5.4 and Laravel Collective's Form & HTML Builder (https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html).

I have a dynamic form, like this:
https://codepen.io/matedon/pen/BZQymW

There are more input fields with the same name but with square bracket:

```
<input name="apartments[][price]">
<input name="apartments[][rooms]">
<input name="apartments[][price]">
<input name="apartments[][rooms]">
```

With the Laravel Collective's Form & HTML Builder the output and the old() value should be that:

```
{
    "apartments": [
        {
            "price": "23000",
            "rooms": "12"
        },
        {
            "price": "42000",
            "rooms": "32"
        }
    ]
}
```

But there is an issue and I got this:

```
@php(dump(Form::old('apartments')))
array:1 [▼
    "price" => "23000"
]
```

I also tried Laravel's "native" solution which is wrong too:

```
@php(dump(session()->getOldInput('apartments')))
array:4 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
        "price" => "23000"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
        "rooms" => "12"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
        "price" => "42000"
    ]
    3 => array:1 [▼
        "rooms" => "32"
    ]
]
```

What is the solution could be?
Thank you!

Comment: I thought `old` only applied to session flash data

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing in the construction of the inputs, in case you want something like this:

```
"apartments" => array:2 [
  "price" => array:2 [
    0 => "52.5"
    1 => "65"
  ]
  "rooms" => array:2 [
    0 => "3"
    1 => "4"
  ]
]
```

Your inputs should look like:

```
<input name="apartments[price][]">
<input name="apartments[rooms][]">
<input name="apartments[price][]">
<input name="apartments[rooms][]">
```

If you need them to be separated by apartment you need to add some type of index (since it is a dynamic form you may need to keep the current index stored somewhere in your application):

```
"apartments" => array:2 [
  1 => array:2 [
    "price" => "52.5"
    "rooms" => "3"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "price" => "65"
    "rooms" => "4"
  ]
]
```

Your inputs:

```
<input name="apartments[1][price]">
<input name="apartments[1][rooms]">
<input name="apartments[2][price]">
<input name="apartments[2][rooms]">
```

Note that this is not the framework fault, it is more a form structure issue. If you need more information about how to build form datasets I'd recommend you to check [W3C HTML5 Forms section](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set).

Hope this helps you.